# Same UITableViewDataSource for two UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm developing an iPhone application with latest SDK and XCode 4.5.2.

On a ViewController I have two `UITableView`. Both use the same `UITableViewDataSource`. My question is about `static NSString* CellIdentifier;`.

Can I do the following?

```
- (UITableViewCell* )tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* CellIdentifier;
    SingletonGlobalVars* singleton = [SingletonGlobalVars sharedInstance];

    if ([tableView isEqual:shopsList])
    {
        CellIdentifier = @"ShopCell";
    }
    else
    {
        CellIdentifier = @"ProductCell";
    }

   [ ... ]
}
```

I need to change `CellIdentifier` but I don't know if I can do this with **a static variable**.

Comment: Set two different tags for each tableview object and check the tag. May this work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would work, but using a static variable does not make sense in your case. Just use a local variable. Note also that you can compare the pointers to `UITableView` directly, it is not necessary to use `isEqual` here.

```
NSString* cellIdentifier;
if (tableView == shopsList)
{
   cellIdentifier = @"ShopCell";
}
else
{
   cellIdentifier = @"ProductCell";
}
```

(I assume that `shopsList` is one of the table views.)

Answer (score -1):

Static variables can be assigned value only once.

You could use two different CellIdentifiers in this case like -

```
static NSString* CellIdentifierShop = @"ShopCell";
static NSString* CellIdentifierProduct = @"ProductCell";
```

Please let me know if it works :)

Comment: Thanks. That was a new learning for me :)
Probably i got confused with something else.
Thanks anyways :)